# How to use an event trigger in WP8.1 with MVVM Light?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light

In a WPF aplication, to use a command with MVVM Light I use this:

```
xmlns:j="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"


<j:Interaction.Triggers>
        <j:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"> 
            </cmd:EventToCommand>
        </j:EventTrigger>
</j:Interaction.Triggers>
```

But in WP8.1 I can't use iteractivity, so I don't know how to use triggers and the EventToCommand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"

<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
        <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"/>
    </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but the problem with this way is that in WPF MVVM Light allows to pass the original event args, but in this way I think that is not possible. In this way I can get the original event args in my viewModel?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía I'm not sure what you are using this for, so it makes it difficult to answer. But if you bind to any property and set the `Mode=TwoWay` then your view model should update accordingly. If the binding property is not supported in your view you can create a `Converter` to convert the data between your view and view model.